# Ambiguous reference to member 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)' connect to server

Tags: ios, json, swift3, nsurlsession

I'm trying to connect to server

Please if you got solution write it down for me

how can I know what changes in newer version of swift?

a lot of differences exist between swift 2 and swift 3

Is swift 4 a lot different than swift 3?

in swift 3 I get this error:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: server.execute())
{Data,URLResponse,error in
    if error != nil{
    print(error as Any)
        return
    }
    do{
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: .allowFragments)
        if let json_result = json as? [String: Any]
        {
            let result = json_result ["result"] as? String
            if result == "0"
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Incorrect Username",message : "The username you entered doesn't appear to belong to an account. Please check your username and try again", preferredStyle : .alert)
                    let alert_action = UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(alert_action)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(result!, forKey: "user_id")
                    //" use of unresolved identifier 'result' "
                    let current_view=UIApplication.shared.windows[0] as UIWindow
                    let new_view=(self.storyboard? .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab_bar"))! as UIViewController
                    UIView.transition(from: (current_view.rootViewController? .view)!, to:new_view.view , duration: 0.65, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: {(action) in current_view.rootViewController=new_view
                    })
                }

            }
        }
        else{
            // Error in jsonSerialization
        }   }
    catch{
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly the return value of `server.execute()`. Maybe it's a `NSURL` or `NSURLRequest` rather than `URL` or `URLRequest`. Maybe it's an optional. Maybe it's something completely different. Bottom line, if the parameter to `dataTask` is not a non-optional `URL` or `URLRequest`, you can get the error you did. Without seeing what `execute` returns, we're just guessing, but it's the likely culprit.

---

A couple of unrelated observations:

1. I wouldn't use `Data` or `URLResponse` as parameter names to the `dataTask` closure. Those are names of data types. I would use `data` and `response` (or don't even specify `response` because you're not using it), instead, to avoid confusion (for both you and the compiler).
2. You have a lot of extraneous casts that only add noise to the code. E.g. `windows` is an array of `UIWindow`, so why bother doing `as UIWindow` when you get the first item from that array.
3. You have a couple of optional chaining sequences that you later force unwrap. There's no point in doing that. Eliminate the optional chaining in that process. Thus, instead of `storyboard?` followed by `!` later:

   ```
   let new_view = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab_bar"))! as UIViewController
   ```

   You can just use `storyboard!`:

   ```
   let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab_bar")
   ```
4. You've got a couple of extraneous options that you can remove if you want. E.g. `.allowFragments` for `JSONSerialization` is unnecessary (and probably undesirable). Or a `completion` of `nil` for your `UIAlertAction` and `present` is unnecessary, too. Not a big deal, but it just adds noise to your code.
5. As a matter of convention, we don't use `_` characters to separate words in a variable name. We use camelCase. So, for example, rather than `current_view`, we'd use `currentView`. (Or, because that's a window, I'd actually use `window`, which is even simpler.)
6. There's no point in using `do`-`try`-`catch` pattern if you're not doing anything in the `catch` block. Why throw an error if you're not going to do anything when you catch it. Just use `try?` if all you care about is whether it succeeded or not.

Thus, the code can be cleaned up a bit to something like:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    guard let data = data,
        let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any],
        let result = json["result"] as? String else {
            print("no result")
            return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if result == "0" {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Incorrect Username", message: "The username you entered doesn't appear to belong to an account. Please check your username and try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .default)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(result, forKey: "user_id")
            let window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
            let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tab_bar")
            UIView.transition(from: window.rootViewController!.view, to: controller.view, duration: 0.65, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, completion: { _ in
                window.rootViewController = controller
            })
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Now, I've replaced `server.execute()` with `request` because I don't know what `execute` is doing, but use whatever is appropriate (see the beginning of this answer).